# "Unknown property" warning for every .css file and line in javafx

Tags: java, css, eclipse, javafx, javafx-2

I'm having an issue when I import my team's group project from git, when imported to Eclipse I have to add the JavaFX SDK from the build path library and once I open up my style package with the .css files in it they all have yellow warning lines underneath each line of code. For example:

```
.label {
    -fx-font-size: 12pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Helvetica bold";
    -fx-text-fill: #000000;
    }
```

the warning message would be:

```
Unknown property: "-fx-font-size: 12pt"
```

It has this warning for every .css file and every line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue and rectified it by ensuring I had included all of the JAR's and Libraries that I required in the Build Path. I had to add Joda Time JAR, SQLite Jar, SceneBuilder Jar and the JavaFX SDK Library.

It is also important to leave these files 'unticked' in the Order and Export section of the Java Build Path.

Comment: The "JavaFX SDK" library part is what I was missing - it's now working great!

Answer (score 2):

You should install [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html)

[image]

I assume you have [Web Tools Platform](https://eclipse.org/webtools/) installed already.

Comment: had web tools downloaded but realized when you mentioned it there was a bug in the installation so re-installed and everything works fine, thanks