# How can I disable `Unknown property: ` error in eclipse while writing JavaFx css

Tags: css, eclipse, javafx

How can I disable `Unknown property:` error in eclipse while writing JavaFx css properties on Eclipse Mars?

For example: `Unknown property: "-fx-background-color"` in `-fx-background-color: #CCFF99;`

Answer (score 24):

Right click on your project and go to build path > Configure build path.
Under libraries, click on "Add library..." button.
Add JavaFX SDK to your project. This will resolve your issue.

[image: Add Library]

Comment: Could this be used for Maven projects?

Comment: I believe the choice JavaFX SDK only becomes available if the e(fx)clipse plug-in has been installed. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.) This is available through help/EclipseMarketplace.

Comment: @Line I am able to use this with a Java 8 Maven project, yes. I don’t believe it affects dependencies in `pom.xml`.

Comment: How to do this for maven projects without importing any library?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure since I can't reproduce this issue, but do you have e(fx)clipse installed? If not, try installing it- it seems to help Eclipse to be more compatible with javaFX.

If you already have it, or if it doesn't help, try the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817620/how-to-disable-css-warning-unknown-property-in-eclipse-mars/32090391#32090391), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766927/unknown-property-warning-for-every-css-file-and-line-in-javafx), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130489/ide-efxclipse-not-working-properly).